# How to use "readline()" function in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I was learning [去哪儿网-2017笔试题](http://www.cnblogs.com/SHERO-Vae/p/5945294.html) and programing. In my program, I want to use `readline()` function to read a single line from input from `stdin`. I know that  `readline()` function belongs to **JavaScript Shell** according to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Projects/SpiderMonkey/Introduction_to_the_JavaScript_shell#readline.28.29). But the function is not defined when I run the code in my browser.

```js
var line;
while (line = read_line()) {
  while (line.indexOf(" ") != -1) {
    line = line.replace(" ", "");
  }
  if (line.length <= 6) {
    print(line);
  } else if (line.length > 6 && line.length <= 14) {
    var line1 = line.substring(0, 6);
    var line2 = line.substring(6);
    print(line1 + " " + line2);
  } else if (line.length > 14 && line.length <= 18) {
    var line1 = line.substring(0, 6);
    var line2 = line.substring(6, 14);
    var line3 = line.substring(14);
    print(line1 + " " + line2 + " " + line3);
  }
}
```

If I want to run the code in my browser. What should I do?

Thank you very much.

Comment: From where are you expecting to read? You do not have a file. Browser based JS does not have stdin - or are you talking node.js?

Comment: You can't read from stdin in javascript

Comment: It's for the js shell *command line* program which has nothing to do with js within a web browser.  Where would it even read from?

Comment: The function, and the mdn page you link to, are about writing programs for the *JavaScript shell*, `jsc`. You can't run it in a browser.

Comment: @mplungjan its `jsc`. Predates (and largely superceded by) node.

Comment: You could just take the input and then use "string.split('\n')" to get the lines into an array and then store it in a variable for example "lines" then to get the line you want just call "lines[0]" where "0" can be replaced with any line number.

Comment: For this question, this link might be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5396020/is-there-a-way-to-read-standard-input-with-javascript

Answer (score 1):

As you mentioned above and the documentation says [Introduction to the JavaScript shell](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Projects/SpiderMonkey/Introduction_to_the_JavaScript_shell#readline.28.29)

it is a command line options and you have to run that over the command shell. Also, you can check [SpiderMonkey](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Projects/SpiderMonkey) to have a better understanding.